# C# WPF -> How to get the coordinates from a stretched(uniform) polygon on a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, polygon

I searched a lot to find a solution for my problem. Couldn't find anything.

This is what I do:

I render a polygon via point array on a grid. The polygon autoresizing itself to match the grids size(uniform). I get the new stretched coordinates with the following lines and create the ellipses with a method:

```
var transform = myPolygon.RenderedGeometry.Transform;
foreach (var point in myPolygon.Points)
{
    var transformedPoint = transform.Transform(point);
    CreateEllipse(5, 5, Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(transformedPoint).Split(';')[0]), Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(transformedPoint).Split(';')[1]), gridPoly);
}

Ellipse CreateEllipse(double width, double height, double desiredCenterX, double desiredCenterY, Grid grid)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse { Width = width, Height = height };
    double left = desiredCenterX - (width / 2);
    double top = desiredCenterY - (height / 2);
    ellipse.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    ellipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkBlue;
    ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(ellipse);
    return ellipse;
}
```

The problem is, if I put the polygon on a grid and the ellipses afterwards, they will render exact the half size and not at the correct position, not even relative. Same happens if I set stretch to 'none'.

If I render my polygon and ellipses on a canvas, they render exact on each polygon point and everything is perfect. Beside, canvas doesn't support stretch.Uniform. And I need to dynamically fit the polygon into its parent object.

My question is, how do I render ellipses on an auto resizing polygon using the point positiondata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take two more things into account.

First, the Grid may align (i.e. move) the whole stretched Polygon according to its HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties. If you don't want to calculate that by yourself, you could get an appropriate GeneralTransform object by `myPolygon.TransformToAncestor(grid)`:

```
var polygonGeometryTransform = myPolygon.RenderedGeometry.Transform;
var polygonToGridTransform = myPolygon.TransformToAncestor(gridPoly);

foreach (var point in myPolygon.Points)
{
    var transformedPoint = polygonToGridTransform.Transform(
                           polygonGeometryTransform.Transform(point));
    CreateEllipse(5, 5, transformedPoint.X, transformedPoint.Y, gridPoly);
}
```

Second, when you do an absolute positioning of the Ellipses relative to the upper left corner of the Grid, you would have to set their HorizontalAlignment to `Left` and the VerticalAlignment to `Top`:

```
ellipse.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
ellipse.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
grid.Children.Add(ellipse);
```

That said, you wouldn't typically set an element's Margin for absolute positioning. It would be much cleaner to use a separate Canvas for the Ellipses and set their `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.

Comment: Everything works now properly, thanks. When I add the ellipses to the grid the first time right after the polygon creation method, it takes the original positions. I think because the polygon hasen't yet rendered in this tick. If I do it separately with a button, the polygon has rendered and it takes the new stretched positions. Do you know a way, doing both without a separate button click?

Comment: You might do it in a SizeChanged event handler of the Grid (which you would have to do anyway). However, make sure that you delete all existing Ellipses before adding new ones.

Comment: Right, didn't thought about it. Thanks again. Now I can finally finish my project.